# ERROR: Swarm deployment failed with code Failed in docker cloud + azure

Tags: azure, docker, docker-swarm, docker-for-windows, docker-cloud

I'm using docker for windows
I use this tutorial(video) to use docker swarm with azure
I did all steps
enable azure for docker - [Image](http://prntscr.com/gpn48u)
create a swarm - [image](http://prntscr.com/gpn33h)
configure it - [Image](http://prntscr.com/gpn3j3)
Set my ssh key - [Image](http://prntscr.com/gpn5lx)

I save it and wait, after so much time i get this error on my swarm log

```
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Running
Deployment state: Failed
ERROR: Swarm deployment failed with code Failed
[2017-09-25T20:25:33.2918462Z] Create swarm-worker-vmss (Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets): Failed/BadRequest (in PT12.6616254S)
[2017-09-25T20:25:28.8563557Z] Create swarm-manager-vmss (Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets): Failed/BadRequest (in PT8.3178482S)
[2017-09-25T20:07:48.4058092Z] Create externalSSHLoadBalancer (Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers): Succeeded/Created (in PT1.6730221S)
[2017-09-25T20:07:46.8242589Z] Create externalLoadBalancer (Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers): Succeeded/Created (in PT4.3058012S)
[2017-09-25T20:07:46.484033Z] Create dbvalidator-swarm2-externalSSHLoadBalancer-public-ip (Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses): Succeeded/OK (in PT9.4003703S)
[2017-09-25T20:07:44.0418665Z] Create dbvalidator-swarm2-vnet (Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks): Succeeded/OK (in PT6.9654022S)
[2017-09-25T20:25:20.1033629Z] Create t654xsw4fmtu2docker (Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts): Succeeded/OK (in PT17M43.0363976S)
[2017-09-25T20:07:42.4619122Z] Create dbvalidator-swarm2-externalLoadBalancer-public-ip (Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses): Succeeded/OK (in PT5.3856603S)
[2017-09-25T20:07:42.0534062Z] Create c4gvzfbdvcd2glogs (Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts): Succeeded/OK (in PT4.9763302S)
[2017-09-25T20:25:15.9817873Z] Create qz5vif5ckmf7qdocker (Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts): Succeeded/OK (in PT17M38.878232S)
[2017-09-25T20:25:06.3213524Z] Create 62ks5i4oesow4docker (Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts): Succeeded/OK (in PT17M29.2539245S)
[2017-09-25T20:25:17.3631569Z] Create h7wrtkxoc3vt4docker (Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts): Succeeded/OK (in PT17M40.2861594S)
[2017-09-25T20:25:10.0146505Z] Create bmhytikhqysymdocker (Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts): Succeeded/OK (in PT17M32.910958S)
[2017-09-25T20:25:34.4608018Z] EvaluateDeploymentOutput: Failed/Conflict (in PT0.8143497S)
```

and when i try see the nodes on my docker cloud console, i get this error

```
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_cloud_46db076d-e1b3-4595-9e12-dca66a29a0a2/v1.30/nodes: open //./pipe/docker_cloud_46db076d-e1b3-4595-9e12-dca66a29a0a2: The system can't find the specific file.
```

Comment: which account are you use? Co-admin of your subscription? By the way, cloud you please show me more error logs from Azure portal.we can find the logs from `resource group`--> `deployments`, please check it. By the way, for test, please use that account to create VMSS via Azure portal.

Comment: i have a Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN subscription and i'm admin

Comment: For test, could you please use that account to create `ACS swarm' via Azure portal?

Comment: I know it's been several months. Were you able to fix your issue, @ItaloJosé? I am experiencing the same issue and haven't found anything helpful.

Comment: thanks @JasonYe-MSFT , you saved my day, the error was crystal clear inside the Azure logs